# c++ advanced feature for non-cpu hardware

Tags: c++, renderscript

in the blog of renderscript
 
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/renderscript.html 

it has mentioned that

> The advanced C++ features are very difficult to run on non-cpu hardware.

so I would like to ask 
what are the 'advanced features' that this paragraph refers to ?

thanks

Comment: Hardware that doesn't have a cpu - what?

Comment: @Bali C: I'm guesssing that would be the GPUs - although it might be more precise to say "non-traditional/parallel processing architectures".

Comment: @ Piskvor Yeah I reckon your right +1!

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider two things hard: virtual functions, and exceptions. These affect program flow in a complex way. GPU's are rather simple in that respect, they don't even like branches.

Note that function pointers are also hard, and you do have those in C. In fact, you'd have more of them: `qsort()` needs a function pointer, but `std::sort` doesn't.

Comment: thanks MSalters, but can you illustrate more about this? or can you provide some references for GPU architecture or what are the main difference between CPU and GPU so those C++ advanced features cannot be portable?  thanks..

Comment: GPU's are very good at long linear lists of instructions, and simple loops (the `for (i=0;i<10;++i)` kind). Modern GPU's _can_ use function pointers, and C++ features can be built on top, but it's not fast.